# Circular (endless) recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement an endless circular `RecyclerView` but can't get it working correctly. Here's what I have so far:

```
// ----------
// Setup
// ----------

private final IntHolder mEndlessScrollRealItemCount = new IntHolder(0);
// TODO: should be calculated instead; makes sure, that there are enough items above and below the real content to fill the screen
private final int mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom = 15; 

// ------------
// Adapter
// ------------

mAdapter = new FastItemAdapter<IItem>() {

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                if (super.getItemCount() == 0) {
                    mEndlessScrollRealItemCount.set(0);
                    return 0;
                }
                mEndlessScrollRealItemCount.set(super.getItemCount());
                return super.getItemCount() + 2 * mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                int index = getIndex(position);
                int realCount = super.getItemCount();
                L.d("getItemViewType - Pos => Index: %d => %d (Size: %d)", position, index, realCount);
                return super.getItemViewType(getIndex(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
                super.onBindViewHolder(holder, getIndex(position), payloads);
            }

            private int getIndex(int position) {
                int realCount = super.getItemCount();
                int index = position;
                if (realCount == 0) {

                } else if (position < mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom) {
                    index = realCount - (mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom - position);
                } else if (position >= realCount + mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom) {
                    index = position - mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom - realCount;
                } else {
                    index = position - mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom;
                }
                while (index < 0) {
                    index += realCount;
                }
                index %= realCount;
                L.d("Pos => Index: %d => %d (Size: %d)", position, index, realCount);
                return index;
            }
        };
        rvSidebar.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int firstItemVisible = RecyclerViewUtil.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(rvSidebar);
                int c = mEndlessScrollRealItemCount.get();
                L.d("firstItemVisible %d, (Size: %d)", firstItemVisible, c);
                if (firstItemVisible > 0 && firstItemVisible >= c + mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom) {
                    // When position reaches end of the list, it should go back to the beginning
                    int over = firstItemVisible - (c + mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom);
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom + over);
                    L.d("firstItemVisible scroll (end reached): %d => %d", firstItemVisible, mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom);
                } else if (firstItemVisible <= mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom - 1) {
                    // When position reaches beginning of the list, it should go back to the end
                    int before = mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom - 1 - firstItemVisible;
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(c + mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom - 1 - before);
                    L.d("firstItemVisible scroll (start reached): %d => %d", firstItemVisible, c + mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom - 1);
                }
            }
        });

// ----------------------------------
// Helper function in RecyclerViewUtil
// ----------------------------------

public static Integer findFirstVisibleItemPosition(RecyclerView rv)
{
    if (rv.getLayoutManager() instanceof GridLayoutManager)
        return ((GridLayoutManager)rv.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    else if (rv.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager)
        return ((LinearLayoutManager)rv.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    return null;
}
```

**Explanation**

What I try to do is following:

- add items before/after the list so that when scrolling up/down there are enough items in the list so that the adapter is not trying to reuse an item, that's still visible
- after initialising the `RecyclerView` I scroll to the first item at position `mEndlessScrollExtraItemsTopBottom` so that the user can as well scroll upwards
- I listen to scroll events and try to move the position if the user scrolls behind the real list in the middle or before it to make the scrolling look endless

**Result**

- scrolling down and reaching the end of the core items works, scroll position is moved correctly and endless scrolling works (but correcting the scroll position in the scroll listener is not smooth)
- scrolling up and reaching the first item of the core items, scroll position is never corrected (although calculations are correct, but `recyclerView.scrollToPosition` does not have any effect)

**Problems**

- why does the `recyclerView.scrollToPosition` not work during an upwards scroll?
- if above can be solved, how could I make the scroll position correction smoothly while user scrolls?

**Notes**

- I saw solutions that work with setting the adapter items count to `Integer.MAX` => I don't want to use such an approach and even those solutions need to update the scroll position like I do it...
- my solution is based on `FastAdapter`, which technically is a normal `RecyclerView.Adapter`, this should not make any difference

Comment: Why you don't like the Integer.MAX approach? I think that its not necessary to update the scroll position, how long would it take to 0 or Integer.MAX position?

Comment: @ArielCarbonaro because this won't work forever. I have a sidebar app that is running always and will never be closed, it may run for years (theoretically). And because I don't want to use `Integer.MAX` items because in the environment I use (`FastAdapter`) all items will be iterated and to get this working I would have to change this in the library itself and would have to check (and correct) all side effects... Logically, there should be a position correction based solution as well to this problem and I want to find out if and how I could implement this.

Comment: Wouldn't a doubly linked list be a better datastructure for a 'endless' list?